# Remote access to router

Tags: router

I want to acceces my router at my residence via the internet while I am traveling. However, when I enter 192.168.1.1. Into the browser it takes me to Frontier’s login, which is the router at the place where I am staying at the moment. How do I get around that? Thanks

Comment: VPN to your network through the many choices for VPN software

Comment: 192.168.1.1 is (presumably) your router's internal address on your home network. To access it from the internet, you would need its **external** IP address.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this is to enable remote administration when you're accessing it from your home network, and then accessing it by providing your public IP address (192.168.1.1 is the router's LAN [private] IP address). ***However, even with a non-obvious administrator user name and strong password, this is not recommended; it potentially opens your home network to compromise.*** (The default administrator username is generally obvious - usually blank, 'admin', or 'administrator', possibly upper-case in one or all letters; the default password is generally weak and easily guessed.)

Consult your router's documentation for specifics, and think at least four times (not just twice) about whether you really want to do this.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion.  I will probably forgo trying to access the router due to your cautions.